# Debug certain project among several

Tags: visual-studio

I open two project in VisualStudio2013 "GoodBye" and "SayHello". I open and edit project "SayHello" but when I press button Debug in Top - startup the project "GoodBye".

How select the project "SayHello" as main and then I can sturtup it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the project then choose the option "set as startUp project"

Comment: glad to help :) but if the answer resolved your problem you should mark it as valid

Comment: I have only 12 scores. Add me scores and I mark your answer =)